# Trying to call methods in main method with variable initialized in other methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods, split, static-methods

I am pretty sure i have this all figured out but i have 3 arrays that i initialized not in the main method, but obviously i cant call those arrays when calling the method in the main method, so my question is, with the code i have below is there any way for me to get the methods to recognize them? or what can i do to initialize everything in the main method? i need to have a read in method a grade method an average method and an output method.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Proj5 {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    int lines=0;
    int [] quizKey = {1,1,2,2,1,1,3,2,4,1,3,5,4,1,2};
    String [] userAnswers = new String[100];
    int [][] userIndividualAnswers = new int[quizKey.length][userAnswers.length];
    int [] numCorrect = new int[quizKey.length];

        readInText(lines, userAnswers, quizKey);
        displayOutput(lines, percentCorrect, quizKey, userAnswers, userAnswersInt, numCorrect, grade);

}//end main

public static void readInText(int lines, String userAnswers[], int quizKey[])throws IOException{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("QuizScores.txt"));
        while(inFile.hasNext()){
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            userAnswers[lines] = tokens[1];
            lines ++;


        }// end while loop
    int[][] userAnswersInt = new int[quizKey.length][lines];
    char[] grade = new char[lines];
    double[] percentCorrect = new double[lines];
}// end readInText


public static void gradeSingleQuiz(String tokens[], int lines, int quizKey[], String userAnswers[], int numCorrect[], int userAnswersInt[][], char grade[], double percentCorrect[]){
    for (int j=0; j<=lines; j++){
    numCorrect[j]=0;    
        for (int n=0; n<=quizKey.length; n++){
            userAnswersInt[n][j] = Integer.parseInt(userAnswers[n]);
                if(userAnswersInt[n][j]==(quizKey[n])){
                    numCorrect[j]++;    
            }
                if(numCorrect[j]>=14)

grade[j]='A';
                else if((numCorrect[j]>=12)&&(numCorrect[j]<14))
                    grade[j]='B';
                else if((numCorrect[j]>=11)&&(numCorrect[j]<12))
                    grade[j]='C';
                else if ((numCorrect[j]>=9)&&(numCorrect[j]<11))
                    grade[j]='D';
                else
                    grade[j]='F';

            percentCorrect[j] = numCorrect[j]/quizKey.length;

        }//end for loop
    }//end for loop
    for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){
        System.out.println(tokens[0] + "    " + numCorrect[i] + "    " +
                (percentCorrect[i]) + "    " + grade[i]);   

}
}// end gradeSingleQuiz

public static void averageScore(int lines, double percentCorrect[]){
    for(int d=0; d<=lines; d++){    
        System.out.println("Average: " + percentCorrect[d]);
    }//end for loop
}// end averageScore

public static void displayOutput(String tokens[], int lines, int quizKey[], String userAnswers[], int numCorrect[], int userAnswersInt[][], char grade[], double percentCorrect[]){
    System.out.println("Student ID    # Correct    %Correct    Grade");
        gradeSingleQuiz(tokens, lines, quizKey, userAnswers, numCorrect, userAnswersInt, grade, percentCorrect);
}// end display output

}//end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution would be to make the arrays into global variables in your program... and this might be the simplest idea to port into your solution

another solution would be to return the arrays from the individual functions that are creating them and then call those functions from the main function.

either of these things should do more or less what you want.

Comment: also this seems a lot like homework, which is why I am trying to refrain from giving you a completely specific answer.  I hope, however, that this will be enough for you to solve your problem!  Good luck!

Comment: so if just return each array it will recognize it when i call the method? and yeah this is homework sorry, I'm just stuck and can't what i need to by looking around.